# Error running SQL query on C# - OleDbException was unhandled, characters found after end of SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql

Whenever I run the below event on C# I get the following error message - `OleDbException was unhandled, characters found after end of SQL statement` at the `int affectedRows = (int)command.ExecuteNonQuery();` line. Any idea how I can fix it?

```
private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pgpText.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill the following textbox: PGP");
    }
    else if (teamText.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill the following textbox: Team");
    }
    else
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            string pgp = pgpText.Text;
            string team = teamText.Text;
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='db.mdb'";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE PGP SET PGP=pgp,Team=team WHERE pgp=pgp; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;";
            conn.Open();

            int affectedRows = (int)command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (affectedRows == 0)
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PGP (PGP,Team) VALUES (pgp,team)";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What values are you actually expecting to insert? And why are you using an update command which just "updates" two fields to the same values? Were you actually trying to use parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you were *actually* trying to use parameters - note that your `pgp` and `team` variables in C# aren't being used *at all* in your code. I suspect you want something like:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
{
    string pgp = pgpText.Text;
    string team = teamText.Text;
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='db.mdb'";
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = conn;
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE PGP SET Team=? WHERE PGP=?";
    command.Parameters.Add("team", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = team;
    command.Parameters.Add("pgp", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = pgp;
    conn.Open();

    int affectedRows = (int) command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (affectedRows == 0)
    {
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PGP (Team, PGP) VALUES (?, ?)";
        // Parameters as before
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Note that I've removed the "SELECT @@ROWCOUNT" part from your update - that's not needed as `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected anyway.

A couple of other notes:

- For most database providers, you'd use named parameters instead of positional ones, e.g. `VALUES (@pgp, @team)` and then use the parameter names... but the OLE DB provider in .NET doesn't support these.
- Do *not* use string concatenation for SQL as another answer (possibly deleted by the time you read this) has suggested - that paves the way for [SQL Injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and conversion issues. (And it's messy.)

Comment: Hi Jon - see updated question. What I'm trying to do is 1) detect to see if a particular row with the specified PGP exists 2) if it does then update it with whatever the new PGP/team specified are 3) if it doesn't then create a new row. Right now a new row is being created whenever the pgp is changed.

Comment: @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier: Well the code I've given should do that... although you've updated the question to get rid of the ID field, and it would be odd to update the PGP field when you've already specified its value...

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect that you're only changing the "team" value, using the PGP value as an identifier.